# How to create frame index hierarchy in Deedle C#

Tags: c#, deedle

What is the correct way to produce a multi-level hierarchical index for a Deedle frame in C#?

Following the first snippet on [this page](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/frame.html#Grouping-by-multiple-keys) which suggests applying `GroupRowsBy()` repeatedly for F#:

> ```
> // Group by passanger class and port
> let byClassAndPort = 
>   titanic
>   |> Frame.groupRowsByInt "Pclass"
>   |> Frame.groupRowsByString "Embarked"
>   |> Frame.mapRowKeys Pair.flatten3
>
> // Get just the Age series with the same row index
> let ageByClassAndPort = byClassAndPort?Age
> ```
>
> If you look at the type of `byClassAndPort`, you can see that it is `Frame<(string * int * int),string>`.

However the method `Frame.mapRowKeys()` does not exist in C# so the frame indexes cannot be flattened. Another option is to use `Frame.IndexRowsUsing()` but I am unsure if this results in the same thing as using `GroupRowsBy()` and also does not allow for preserving the original ordinal index.

An example of the snippet above written in C# would be perfect, or an explanation of the correct way to create such a frame in C#.

Thanks.